# Problema no processamento do conteúdo

Tags: ckeditor

Estou sofrendo com um processamento atípico do value da minha textarea manipulada pelo ckeditor. O que posso fazer para evitar o erro exibido nas amostras do Firefox abaixo:

## CKEDITOR @ Chrome for Windows

**1. Editor:**
[image: CKEDITOR @ Chrome]

**2. Pre-visualização do conteúdo do editor:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

## CKEDITOR @ Firefox for Windows

**1. Editor:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**2. Pre-visualização do conteúdo do editor:**
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Tenta config.entities_latin = false; Ou config.entities = false; Ou config.basicEntities = false;

Comment: @Sorack, só para confirmar, qual arquivo devo inserir estes parâmetros?

Comment: config.js se não me engano